# C program skipping over user input?

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

I'm currently making a program that takes the input from a user of how many numbers that they want in an array and which numbers are in those arrays to compare the two to find their unions in intersections.

I have this written but for some reason after the user inputs how many numbers they want and which numbers into the first array(a), it skips the entire user input for the second array(b).

The computations for the union and intersection are correct(not shown) but I just can't figure out what I'm missing. I'm quite new at C so there is probably some minor issue I'm missing.

Thanks for your help!

```
int main(void){

    int i, j, x, y;
    int elemA, elemB;
    int a[10] = {0};
    int b[10] = {0};


    // Prompts user to enter the amount of numbers that will be in array a
    // then asks user to enter the values (0-9) to be inputted.
    printf("Enter the number of elements in set A: \n");
       scanf("%d", &elemA);
    printf("Enter %d number(s) for set A: \n", elemA);
       scanf("%d", &x);
       if(x < 10)
          a[x]=1; // sets the index in the array to 1 if the
                  //corresponding number that has been inputted


    // Prompts user to enter the amount of numbers that will be in array a
    // then asks user to enter the values (0-9) to be inputted.
    printf("Enter the number of elements in set B: \n");
    scanf("%d", &elemB);
    printf("Enter %d number(s) for set B: \n", elemB);
       scanf("%d", &y);
       if(y < 10)
          b[y]=1; // sets the index in the array to 1 if the
                  //corresponding number that has been inputted

*** rest of code ***
```

Comment: `scanf("%d", &x);` only reads one number. You need a loop somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
printf("Enter %d number(s) for set A: \n", elemA);
scanf("%d", &x);
```

You are reading only one int, the others are queued, and will be used when you use scanf other time, without user input.

Comment: That makes so much sense. My code is starting to return some weird numbers now with a for loop but I'll get it. Thanks so much!